# Is there a function like the magic method __call() for global scope in php?

Tags: php

If a call is made to an undefined method in a class, the magic method __call can intercept the call, so I could handle the situation as I see fit:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

Is there any mechanism provided in php whereby I can do the same thing with functions in global scope.
    The point is best illustrated with code:

```
    <?php
    function return_some_array(){
      $a = array();
      //Do stuff to array
      return array();
    }

    // Now i call the function like so:
    $give_me_array = return_some_array();

    // But sometimes I want the array to not contain zeroes, nulls etc.
    // so I call: 
    $give_me_array_filtered = return_some_array_filtered();

    // But i haven't defined return_some_array_filtered() anywhere.
    // Instead I would like to do something like so: 
    function __magic_call($function_name_passed_automatically){ 
      preg_match('/(.*)_filtered$/', $function_name_passed_automatically, $matches);
      $function_name_that_i_defined_earlier_called_return_some_array = $matches[1];
      if($matches){
        $result = call_user_func($function_name_that_i_defined_earlier_called_return_some_array);
        $filtered = array_filter($result);
        return $filtered;
      }
    }

    //So now, I could call return_some_other_array_filtered() and it would work provided I had defined return_some_other_array().
    //Or even Donkey_filtered() would work, provided I had defined Donkey() somewhere.
    ?>
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: The example is not the most convincing one ever (and kinda inevitably triggered some pointy comments below, as you noticed, too :) ), but, for the record: the question is, nevertheless, very much legit. (You could've used something like a non-critical beautification transformation, or an optimization of some sort, or my favorite: a generic HTML "tagification" helper, like `TAG(...)`, where the intercepted call could insert `<TAG>...</TAG>` according to the function name; etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such.

If you had made a static method like return_some_array_filtered::go() then you could use PHP5's  [autoload()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) facility to dynamically create the class and method.  After creation the call proceeds as usual.  You may want to implement [callStatic()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) on that class. Beware dynamically creating a class from scratch (without include()) in PHP is non-trivial.

Comment: @V-A That's of course quite a wasteful and unnecessarily hackish way to do things. You should define and call your functions as normal.

Comment: On another note: do you think this can be implemented as an extension? I would imagine it would be fairly simple?

Comment: @deceze That really is not the point. You are of course entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @V-A It could be done as a straightforward PEAR extension. Note __autoload() can only be defined once so you must use spl_autoload_register() so your extension wont clobber other programmers' __autoload()